# Subclassed UITableViewCell not working with dequeue

Tags: ios, uitableview, subclass

I have subclassed UITableViewCell with  a new class, symbolCell, which has a header, implementation and xib file. I register symbolCell to firstTable, a UITableView, in my mainViewController's viewDidLoad method with the following:

```
UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"symbolCell" bundle:nil];
    [firstTable registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"symbolCell"];
```

I then dequeue the cell later with

```
symbolCell *cellForTableOne = [firstTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"symbolCell"];
```

However, this code creates the error "*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key symbolFieldLabel.'" where symbolFieldLabel is a UILabel on symbolCell. That is, that exact line is where the error occurs. Why is this happening? I have subclassed cells many times before and have never gotten this error.

Comment: Did you check all of the class names used in the XIB?

Comment: That looks like you defined an outlet in the xib, but there is no property in the `UITableViewCell` subclass to store the outlet; or as @Wain said, you forgot to specify the subclass in the xib.

Comment: The xib class name is symbolCell, and when I checked the connections under file owner there was a valid connection to a valid property. Any other ideas? I can't figure it out.

Comment: Just try remove all the IBOutlet connections, and reconnect them again. I used to got the same error when I copy some views in one xib and paste them into another xib, and all the IBOutlets still connect to the old one

Comment: I just tried this and it doesn't seem to work. I'm sure there's a simple solution that I'm just missing.

Comment: I would like to make it clear that the error comes when the cell is dequeued

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the File's Owner to your custom class, set your root view to be your custom UITableViewCell subclass. Then hook up your outlets to the root view.